# Is it possible to change form attr name dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one form which it's dynamic depends on parameters. the form name attribute should be different for each dynamic built form. Is there a way how to change form name attribute?
or sufficient work around?

this way is not working or I'm missing something

```
<form action="get" name="oldname">
</form>

$('#formid').attr('name', 'dynamicname');
```

I'd like to change the "oldname" via client-side javascript so it ends up like this:

```
<form action="get" name="dynamicname">
</form>
```

Thanks

Comment: This should work. What exactly is *not working*?

Comment: it's not changing the name attribute it's always the same

Comment: are you inserting the form dynamically into the DOM?

Comment: How did you check it's not working? These dynamic changes are often not visible when viewing source. You need firebug or something to inspect changed attr. Or have you submited the form and checked it server-side?

Comment: it works for me u sure the form id matches?

Comment: $('#formid').attr('name', 'dynamicname'); This way is giving me error: Object doesn't support this property or method. I don't how it works for you

Answer (score 0):

well this is incorrect $('#formid').attr('name', 'dynamicname');

you are expecting the forms id field to be formid and then changing the attr. in this case you should use the following: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

hope that helps.

Comment: This example shows how to select based on tag and attr value not how to change attr value unfortunately –

Comment: yes, because you're trying to select a form with the id 'formid' and the form in your example doesn't have that.

Comment: i have no clue what you want to do. wiht your current implementation i gave u an aswer, i also pointed out what is wrong with the current implementation. I cant tell u something that you cannot..